# Uninstalling a package installed with amazon-linux-extras

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux-extras

How do you UNinstall a package installed with amazon-linux-extras??

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install postgresql10
```

Installs it. Now... how do I remove it?

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras uninstall postgresql10
```

Nope.

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras remove postgresql10
```

Nope.

```
yum remove postgresql10
```

Nope.

WTH?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sudo yum remove postgresql
```

In order to confirm we are removing what we did install with `amazon-linux-extras`, we can check the `Repository` after we run the `sudo yum remove` command:

[image]

Comment: sudo yum remove : command does not give above output.

Comment: okay, but what output do you get then?

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo amazon-linux-extras info postgresql10` to list the yum package names to uninstall, then uninstall them by running `sudo yum remove [package-list]`.